# Microsoft edge extension pending review

Tags: microsoft-extensions-logging

I uploaded my extension on 22 sep , since then it is showing pending review status. Now i would like to know-

If we uploaded the extension on Microsoft edge extension add ons . Then we also need to upload on Google Chrome web store?

Did we need to pay registration or any other kinds of fee for your extension to get review?

Someone please guide.